# App rejected, i need access to SEND_SMS to send notifications to customers, how can i get approved?

Tags: android, google-play, sms, android-permissions, google-play-console

I already got rejected twice.

Your app appears to have an invalid exception use case declaration.
You declared that your app provides device automation for users as a core functionality, but we couldn’t verify this.

My app uses the SEND_SMS permission to send SMS messages to customers for notifying them when they get points, redeem points for items, and when they gain a free item for their account. I have a loyalty rewards app. Which category does my app fit in so i can get my update accepted. I have already tried Device Automation, Default Sms Handler, and Services- Carrier. All these checkboxes have been rejected. Which one do i chose to get approved? i send video instructions and i still get denied please help. Should i just appeal? here is the following list of checkboxes:

Default SMS handler

Default Phone handler

Default Assistant handler

Transactional backup and restore for users and archive for enterprise (time-limited/non-continuous)

Enterprise archive, CRM, and device management

Caller ID, spam detection, and blocking

Connected device companion apps (for example, smartwatch or automotive)

Cross-device synchronization or transfer of SMS or calls

SMS-based financial transactions and related activity where access is restricted to financial SMS transactions (for example, 5-digit messages)

SMS based money management

Proxy calls

Services - Carrier

Services - OEM

Device Automation

Physical safety / emergency alert apps (e.g., senior safety)

Call-based OTP account verification

Using SMS_CB_RECEIVED for customer communications (e.g., Smart Zone Cast service)

Write and Show Call History in Dialer

In-vehicle hands-free use or projected display

Anti-SMS Phishing

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: None. Your app should not send SMS for promotions. If you want to do this, you need to send SMS from a backend and not from the users phone.

Comment: edited my question again, for notifying them when they get points, redeem points for items, and when they gain a free item for their account. Its not for promotions. SMS is used for notifications of points and their use.

Answer (score 0):

I would use one of my own cellphones in order to send SMS messages to my customers. As a provider, I know when my customers gain points, and thus I can automate the SMS by writing a small app, which runs on my cellphone, and gets its information from a remote database, for example.